# Are there any open-source phoneme sets (for speech synthesis)?

Tags: audio, speech, phoneme

I am trying to make a super basic speech synthesizer, and I need some form of phoneme audio files so that I can piece them together and build words. Are there any open phoneme sets that I would be able to use for this?

Comment: I ended up recording myself with Audacity and splitting it up into individual phonemes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For super basic speech synthesizer it's worth to check espeak http://espeak.sourceforge.net, it's better than to glue sound files together.

Answer (score 0):

This may be more than you're looking for, but have you checked into http://www.vocaloid.com/en/ by any chance?  There are many speech products on the market.  You might also be interested in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361572(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I have vocaloid, but I am looking for a bunch of separate sound files. I'll take a look at the microsoft speech stuff, but I don't think it will be what I need.